# Laravel Eloquent condition to fetch hierarchy level

Tags: laravel, eloquent, recursive-query

Laravel Eloquent condition to fetch hierarchy level.

I have a table named `routes` and it is `self-referencing`

Sample data:

```
(PK)                    
Id  title       route_id
1   users       null
2   home        null
3   foo         1      
4   bar         3      
5   hoge        3
```

I would want to have a function to get routes according to its hierarchy

```
$this->routes->getByHierarchyLevel(1);
// results                    
Id  title       route_id
1   users       null
2   home        null


$this->routes->getByHierarchyLevel(2);
// results                    
Id  title       route_id
3   foo         1

$this->routes->getByHierarchyLevel(3);
// results                    
Id  title       route_id
4   bar         3      
5   hoge        3
```

**Is there a single chained query builder/eloquent builder possible for this one?**

I already made a custom function of this one but it is a looped query or the other solution is fetch all and filter.

Comment: It would be easier if you can record the level at the time of insertion in table and store that level that can save you from complex queries and overhead

Comment: Thanks, it is actually the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to introduce a new column `level` in your routes table and at the time of insertion detect their nested level and save it in your table, this way you can perform your filters easily without any extra overhead , otherwise you would need complex/expensive queries to be able to detect their level and apply filter

---

| id | title | route_id | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | users | null | 1 |
| 2 | home | null | 1 |
| 3 | foo | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | bar | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | hoge | 3 | 3 |